# Aligning fragments with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, android-linearlayout

I'm having real problems trying to align fragments with a `RelativeLayout`, though it seems this should be straightforward.  I just need two fragments next to each other and if I use a `LinearLayout` it works fine:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <fragment android:name="com.fragment.test.TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentTitles"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

    <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/details" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

However, if I use a `RelativeLayout`, nothing shows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <fragment android:name="com.fragment.test.TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentTitles"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

    <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/details" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragmentTitles"            
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Update:

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
    >
        <fragment android:name="com.fragment1"
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/statusUpdated"
         />

        <fragment android:name="com.fragment2"  
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/statusUpdated"        
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment1"
         />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/statusUpdated" style="@style/Status" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use weights with a `RelativeLayout`. Basically that attribute gets ignored, meaning both your fragments render with a width of `0`, hence they are not visible.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you might want to consider wrapping your first example (the `LinearLayout`) into a `RelativeLayout` - in other words: combine/integrate both layouts. That does result in another level in your view hierarchy though.

---

**Edit:**

I haven't actually tested it, but I reckon something like this is what you're looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer_view" 
        android:weightSum="3">

        <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/fragmentTitles" 
            android:name="com.fragment.test.TitlesFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/footer_view" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#f00" 
        android:text="I am a footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Obviously you can replace the `TextView` with anything you like.

Comment: What I'm ultimately trying to do is add a footer to the bottom of the layout, but I couldn't get it working using a `LinearLayout`.  I was able to get the footer to show using a `RelativeLayout` but then the fragments wouldn't appear, so I was just trying to get the fragments to appear (without the footer), hence my question.  Sounds like I'm going to have to figure out how to get the footer to work using a `LinearLayout`.  I basically want a layout where the left fragment takes up 1/3 of the screen, the right the rest of the screen, with a sticky footer.

Comment: Right, that shouldn't be too hard to realise. Please see the edit in my answer and give that a go. Haven't tried it, but it should be (close to) what you're after.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  I implemented your suggestion, and it worked for the most part, but the footer seems to overlap the last item in the list, so the last item is cut in half.  Ugh, I'm really bad working with Android layouts.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what's going on? If I use the layout as shown above, give the footer a transparent background and set colours to the fragments, then everything stays nicely above the footers. If one of the fragments would be overlapping the footer, I should be seeing that colour behind the footer (because of the transparency). [Screenshot with transparent footer.](http://i.imgur.com/sDVGZ.png)

Comment: @KrisB: On second thought: can you double check you didn't forget to add `android:layout_above="@+id/footer_view"` to the `LinearLayout` containing the fragments? The issue you're describing is typically for not having that constraint, which is crucial for the behavior you want.

Comment: Checkout the screenshot and code I added to the OP.  Gives you a better idea of what I'm seeng, but I have the footer layout outside of the `LinearLayout`

Comment: *I have the footer layout outside of the `LinearLayout`* - That's not what I was suggesting. Please read my previous comment again and have a look at my example layout, because you indeed forgot to add the `layout_above` attribute to the `LinearLayout`. In stead, you seem to have added it to the `LinearLayout`'s children - that won't work. In other words: remove `android:layout_above="@id/statusUpdated"` from those children and add it to the `LinearLayout` as per example given. You can also get rid of `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment1"`; that doesn't have any effect in a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: ah, that was the problem.  I did this late last night, so I probably wasn't in the best frame of mind.  Anyhow, thanks for your help, I appreciate it.  I have a huge mental block when it comes to Android layouts. :)

Comment: You're welcome - we all have those nights. :) Good thing I like fiddling around with layouts.